# Sitecore WFFM custom save action not called

Tags: sitecore

I have created a custom save action in WFFM. After updating the save action to have the correct assembly and fully qualified class name I added the save action to a form and attempted to submit. The form submits and presents the thank you message however the issue is that in the class being invoked the execute method of the save action is never called. I am not sure why this is the case any thoughts?
Here is my custom save action and a link to a picture of how I have configured it.
[WFFM type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDEDg.jpg)

```cs
using Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Shared;
using Sitecore.WFFM.Actions.Base;
using Sitecore.Form.Submit;

namespace Core.Forms {
    public class CustomSaveAction: ISaveAction {
        //custom parameters
        public string SharepointUrl { get; set; }
        public string ListId { get; set; }
        public string MappedFields { get; set; }

        public ID ActionID { get; set; }

        public ActionType ActionType
        {
            get
            {
                return ActionType.Save;
            }
        }

        public ActionState QueryState(ActionQueryContext queryContext) {
            return ActionState.Enabled;
        }

        public string UniqueKey { get; set; }

        public void Execute(ID formId, AdaptedResultList adaptedFields, ActionCallContext actionCallContext = null, params object[] data) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of sitecore are you using?

Comment: We are using Sitecore 8.1 currently.

Comment: Which environment and what is your server set up (e.g. separate CM/CD servers?)

Comment: We do have separate cm/cd servers in other environments however this is just on my dev box. I did see something about needing to check the client action box for the cm/cd split (which I did).

Comment: Also I don't know if this helps or not we have disabled the xdb in the config files.

Comment: It's a web forms or Mvc solution?

Comment: We are using MVC/MVC Forms for all pages that we are using WFFM on. (there are some pages that we have migrated over from our old 6.5 instance in web forms but we aren't using WFFM on them).

Comment: It might be worth noting that in edit mode all the breakpoints for the Enabled and ActionType properties hit. It is only on submission that execute never gets called.

Comment: Can you check if you have on your CM <setting name="WFM.IsRemoteActions" value="true" /> . You need to remove it if you have this setting

Comment: Patched that setting to be false and no luck.

Comment: can you also modify to inherit from wffmsaveaction not from isaveaction? for me is working in this way. I had same issue like you but removing that setting and inherits from wwfmsave action fix it

Comment: I tried that but it is still not hitting the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

So I was testing in chrome and getting frustrated so asked another dev on my team to do a build on his machine and see what happened. Low and behold the break point hit. I tried deleting my local copy and repulling from source control and was still running into the same issue. Upon getting frustrated switching browsers somehow managed to make it work. I am guessing that there is something that chrome is caching that it shouldn't be but either way this is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you update the Execute method and use something like:

```cs
public void Execute(ID formid, AdaptedResultList fields, params object[] data)
{
     Assert.ArgumentNotNull(fields, "fields");
     // Your code here
}
```

Comment: I added that as an overload since I had seen in it a third party's WFFM code however neither the original method or the overload are being called.

Comment: The method signature has changed in WFFM 8.1 so the original in the question is the correct one to use. The above is correct for previous versions of WFFM though.